# What is the best way to solve for a positive semidefinite matrix inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, constraints

Suppose I have the equation $A \leq P U X U^\dagger P$, where A is positive semidefinite, U is unitary, P is a projection, and X is an unknown positive semidefinite matrix, and $\leq$ is the Loewner order.

Now suppose that $X = \Sigma_i I \otimes \ldots X_i \ldots \otimes I$, where each $X_i$ is an unknown positive semidefinite matrix, all the $X_i$ have the same dimensions, but each $X_i$ may be in a different position in the tensor product (or they may be in the same position). For example, $X = X_1 \otimes I \otimes I + I \otimes X_2 \otimes I + I \otimes X_3 \otimes I$.

Is there an analytic way to find a feasible solution for all the $X_i$? Or are there good tools to calculate this? I have been using CVX and other optimization/constraint solvers but, in my specific case, they tend to violate the constraint (the first equation) too frequently.

Comment: By “projection”, do you mean an *orthogonal* projection? If so, then $A\le PUXU^\dagger P$ for some $X$ only if $A=PAP$. When this necessary condition is satisfied, one may simply take $X=U^\dagger AU$.

Comment: @user1551 yes it is an orthogonal projection, but note that solving for $X$ doesn't actually solve for the individual $X_i$, which is mainly what I need to solve for. I'm not sure if this is possible algebraically, and as mentioned the convex optimization tools tend to violate the constraint

Comment: Why is it possible and why do you want to express $X$ that way?

Comment: The motivation would require a lot of explanation for the background, but this is the system that we have to work with. Why is what possible? I'm asking if it's possible. I should provide context that A has the same form as X, and that each $A_i \leq I$, so we can always choose each $X_i = I$ and the equation holds.